# error in your SQL syntax dont know how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i keep getting this error from sql and i dont know how to fix it. below are my coding

> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `car_book` (
  `book_id` int(2) NOT NULL ,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `tel_no` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `model_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `price` double(10) NOT NULL,
  `rental_date` date NOT NULL,
  `return_date` date NOT NULL,
  `no_of_day` int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `user`
--

INSERT INTO `car_book` (`book_id`, `name`, `tel_no`, `model_name`, `price`, `rental_date`, `return_date`, `no_of_day`)
VALUES ([`book_id`],[`name`],[`phone`],[`model_name`],[`rental_date`],[`return_date`],[`no_of_day`]);
```

Comment: The data you are trying to load in the `VALUE()` clause does not match the data types you specify in your table column definitions i.e. the INSERT is nonsense

Comment: You have missed `price` in values.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
`price` double(10) NOT NULL,
```

To:

```
`price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
```

You have to specify the decimal value in case of double. 10,2 means you can store up to 8 numbers and 2 decimal values.